# How to properly encode the special chars coming in the CSV

Tags: php, magento, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I am working on product import for magento using advance data flow profiles and i am facing the common special chars issue that are coming in the CSV i have tried the `htmlspeicalchars function` and `utf8_encode` for encoding the values but they are disturbing the working of `Ganon php parser` as i have html pages from where i grabbing the data and making the CSV of products.

This is really annoying and it has been two days i am pulling my hair to solve this.
Any idea on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to be using these functions, though make sure you use `decode` too before using/showing the values. E.g.: [ut8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

Comment: When i run the advance profile the entire CSV is loading the DB first and then unserilize each row while working.. may be i need to decode the data before  unserilize.